# Details of Marlin's feedrate calculation

Tags: marlin, g-code

I want to programatically generate G-code for a (Marlin-based) Ultimaker 2+ printer, and I have been looking at the [Marlin documentation](https://marlinfw.org/meta/gcode/) and working G-code examples generated by Cura.

This has left me confused about exactly how Marlin interprets the feedrate (F) parameter in G-code commands.

If I move on a single axis (e.g. `G1 F7000 X10` or `G1 F200 E50`), then I assume F simply says how fast that axis should move (ignoring acceleration).

On CNC milling machines I've worked with, the same is true when moving on multiple axes – for instance, `G1 F1000 X10 Y10 Z10` would mean the *tool* moves at 1000mm/min, and therefore the *individual* axes are each moving at 693mm/min.  Which is good, because it means the feedrate doesn't depend on the direction of movement.

But a 3D printer has four axes (E, X, Y, Z), and Marlin only uses a single feedrate parameter.  So do I need to calculate that in four-dimensional space?  In other words,

$F = \sqrt[4]{F_E^4 + F_X^4 + F_Y^4 + F_Z^4} ?$

If that is not correct, how **is** the feedrate related to the feedrates for the individual axes?.

Answer (score 1):

Feedrates are not 4-dimensional, and yes this makes them a bit inconsistent. But physically the 4-dimensional speed would not make any sense - for example, slowing down the E axis while speeding up the X axis would not maintain the same "overall speed" in any meaningful sense.

So, feedrates work differently for:

- Moves with a nonzero X, Y, or Z component: the feedrate is an ideal, desired speed in 3 dimensions, possibly limited by the max feedrates of each axis (including E) individually, as well as their acceleration profiles.
- Extruder-only moves where X, Y, and Z components are all zero: the feedrate is an ideal, desired speed in one dimension: the E axis, and may be limited by the max feedrate and acceleration profile for the E axis.

Comment: Aha!  I did wonder if that was the explanation for how Cura's "print speed" can be the same as the feedrate it uses for printing moves.  I guess it keeps things simple.  The 4D approach wouldn't be completely insane, but it would mean you'd have to continually adjust F to get a constant movement speed or constant extrusion rate.  (FWIW, specifying the end position and time fully determines the solution, so you couldn't actually slow down E while speeding up X)